# Jasmine test positioning of an element

Tags: jquery, bdd, jasmine, backbone-views

I want to test a backbone view that should initially centre itself in its parent container when first instantiated. It's part of a UI that allows the user to drag elements around inside a div.

This current test isn't working (the left and top of the element are set to zero).

I realise that since the parent and child element I created are never inserted into the DOM, their CSS never seems to take on any values. What is the correct way of doing this?

The render function:

```
  $(@el).css
    left: ($(@parent).width() - @el.width) / 2
    top: ($(@parent).height() - @el.height) / 2      
      @
```

The test code

```
it("should center the element", function() {
  var size = { width: 60, height: 90};
  var parent = document.createElement('div');
  $(parent).width(size.width);
  $(parent).height(size.height);

  this.view.parent = parent;
  $(parent).append(this.view.render().el);

  var expectPosition = {
    left: ($(parent).width() - $(this.view.el).width()) / 2,
    top: (size.height - $(this.view.el).height()) / 2,
  }

      expect($(this.view.el).position()).toEqual(expectPosition);
});
```